# How to reset cart details in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created one application for shopping cart. Everything is working good, but i have removed `document.location.href` for redirection instead of i have used `this.router.navigate['/products']`.So cart details is not reset properly. I tried to resolve the issue but not working. If anyone can help to find the solutions?

Comment: Try to reset the list of the cart, by modifying the cart service.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made changes in `src/app/services/cart.service.ts`

```js
 emptyCart(){   
    this.cartData =[];  
    this.listCartItems(); 
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-cnstaj

Reason document.location.href works because after reseting dictionary redirecting to new page.

When you navigate router of Angular its doesnt redirect, its just changes routes. In this reset is not happening.

For clearing cart when click on "Place New Order"

inside function `clearCart()` in checkout.dir.ts

```js
this.cart.emptyCart();
```

before this line :

```
this.router.navigate(['/products']);
```

Comment: I checked in given stackblitz. it working. Can you check again.

Comment: In checkout page after clicked place a new order button How to reset?

Comment: you want to reset cart item when click on  "New order" ?

Comment: Yes..want to reset cart item when click on New order

Comment: added solution.@NilaVaani

Comment: How can i integerate payment gateway? like for netbanking,credit card.debir card,paytm and more others way.  Can you answer this question 59558325?